# Elasticsearch:Unknown command: 'search_index'

Tags: django, postgresql, elasticsearch, kibana

Hi I am trying to implement elasticsearch using django. I am following this tutorial

> https://www.codementor.io/samueljames/using-django-with-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-9l4fwx138

I am getting ,

```
Unknown command: 'search_index'
```

Type 'manage.py help' for usage.

when trying to create index using cmd

```
python manage.py search_index --rebuild
```

please help

Comment: please show your `INSTALLED_APPS` block in the `settings`

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
  # .... 
    'django_elasticsearch_dsl',
]

Answer (score 8):

The issue could be not adding `django-elasticsearch-dsl` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in Django. (This is available in settings.py file)